# Get WordPress featured image for Facebook Opengraph

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have tried a few different ways to call the page's featured image for the Facebook opengraph meta tag.

Example

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); ?>" />
```

The issue I have is this also calls the image width, class and includes inside an ahref

How can I call ONLY the direct image url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use wp_get_attachment_image_src() for that:

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full')[0]; ?>
```